# bad bind variable Triggers pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this common problem with the trigger I created. I spent long time looking through any error but I could not find anything wrong though!
I am intending to create a trigger over my the table orders to be fired to warn the users when items in the ORDER reaches the re-order level.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ORDERS_CHECK AFTER 
   INSERT OR UPDATE ON ORDERS
   FOR EACH ROW 
   DECLARE
   V_QTY ODETAILS.QTY%TYPE;
   V_QOH PARTS.QOH%TYPE;
   V_OLEVEL PARTS.OLEVEL%TYPE;
   V_LEVEL_STATS EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   SELECT DOD.QTY, P.QOH, P.OLEVEL INTO V_QTY, V_QOH, V_OLEVEL
   FROM   PARTS P, ODETAILS OD
   WHERE  P.PNO =  OD.PNO
   AND    OD.QTY = :NEW.QTY;

IF :OLD.QTY <= :NEW.V_OLEVEL THEN 
  RAISE V_LEVEL_STATS;
ELSE 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Process has been completed successfully');
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN V_LEVEL_STATS THEN
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Warning: Product with ID '|| :OLD.PNO ||'    
    contains only '|| :NEW.QTY ||' left over!');
END;
```

Compiler Error:

```
  Error(13,17): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.QTY'
  Error(15,5): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.QTY'
  Error(15,17): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.V_OLEVEL'
  Error(23,64): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.PNO'
  Error(23,95): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.QTY'
```

Comment: So, what is the specific error, and where?

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to include the errors!

Comment: Do you think I have done something wrong?

Comment: Does the `qty` column exist on the `orders` table?  e.g. Does `SELECT qty FROM orders WHERE rownum <2; ` return anything?

Comment: QTY belongs to Odetails table !

Comment: The trigger is acting on the `orders` table.  Therefore the pseudorecords (`:OLD.column`, `:NEW.column`) only exist for that table.  [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955).  Why would the trigger be able to "know" about values that may or may not be changing (in the past or future) for another table when it fires **only** when there is a change for the `orders` table?

Comment: It's part of my uni course work. The scenario is the DBA should make sure the stock in had should be refilled as items get ordered. An alert message should warn the user if the QOH is equal or less than the Olevel. I got confused in that bit. Do you think trigger should be on parts table?

Comment: I altered the trigger to be fired on the ODETAILS table as it contains the quality of the orders, but this made me debate with myself  about QOH and OLEVEL that reside in parts and the trigger should rely the quality of orders from odetails.

Comment: In the first line of the SELECT statement in your trigger you have `DOD.QTY`. There is no table in this SELECT statement with an alias of `DOD`. Try changing this to `OD.QTY` and see if this corrects your problem. Best of luck.